# CSS and Images won't load properly on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I have my own theme with custom templates, and I tested my pages using my laptop and it works.

But when I connect my mobile device / tablet to the same WIFI Connection / Lan Connection, the CSS and Images won't load correctly.

Take note: I used the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function to reference every CSS, JS and image files that I use for my theme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its should include like this for CSS files in functions.php

```
function themes_style(){

wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

}
```

For JS its should include like this in functions.php

```
function theme_js(){
wp_register_script('flexslider' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/flexslider.js' , array('jquery') ,true);

}
```